# How to replace list of words with <span> tag at multiple indexes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, string

I have a response of parent string which I have to modify and replace with the provided start and end indexes.

```
let parentString = '\r\nManchester United won\r\nManchester City lost\r\nLeeds United tied'

let replaceValues = 
    {value: 'Manchester United', startIndex: 2, endIndex: 19}
    {value: 'Manchester City', startIndex: 25, endIndex: 40}
    {value: 'Leeds United', startIndex: 47, endIndex: 59}
```

Expected Final Result:

[image]

I tried below approach but was not successful

```
replaceAt(input: string, index: number, replacement: string, source: string) {
    return (
      input.substring(0, index) +
      replacement +
      input.substring(index + source.length)
    );
  }
```

Usage:

```
replaceValues.forEach((replaceMatch: any) => {
        parentString =  this.replaceAt(
              parentString,
              replaceMatch.startIndex,
              "<span class='replace-text-{{i}}'>${replaceMatch.value}</span>",
              replaceMatch.value
            );
```

please ignore my example names couldn't think anything more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** My previous answer did not account to duplicate and did not use your indexes, so here it is a more consistent answer:

Convert string to array to ease manipulation

```js
const parentArray = Array.from(parentString)
```

Now we have an array of characters, i.e `[" ", " ", "M", "a", "n", "c", "h", ...]`

For each item in `replaceValues` we use splice on our newly created array. Splice acctepts 3 arguments:

1. First argument is the start index where we want to splice the array.
2. Second argument is how many items in the array will be deleted/replaced.
3. Third argument is with what we want to replace the array portion.

```js
let numberOfCharsReplaced = 0

replaceValues.forEach(item => {
  parentArray.splice(item.startIndex - numberOfCharsReplaced, item.endIndex - item.startIndex, `<span>${item.value}</span>`)
  numberOfCharsReplaced = numberOfCharsReplaced + item.endIndex - item.startIndex - 1
  console.log(parentArray, numberOfCharsReplaced)
})
```

That `numberOfCharsReplaced` is necessary because since we splice and replace, we need to take account of the number of chars that has been replaced, what I am saying is that when we replace the 'Manchester United' word that has 16 chars, we pass from 16 items in the array to only 1 big word (i.e `"<span>Manchester United</span>"`) so we can't rely on the startIndex of the next value only, we need to do some calculation. It's easier in the code.

We get back our string by using `.join()`, telling to the join method with which character we want to join each character.

```js
const replacedParentString = parentArray.join("");
```

If you still wish to have an array of html string, use the `split` and `shift` method indicated in the old answer

Please refer to MDN to read more about the methods used in this answer

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
[join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

---

#### OLD ANSWER

Use values to replace names with their 'html' equivalent within the parent string

```js
replaceValues.forEach(item => {
  parentString = parentString.replace(item.value, `<span>${item.value}</span>`)
})
```

Now you have a string that is like this:

`\r\n<span>Manchester United</span> won\r\n<span>Manchester City</span> lost\r\n<span>Leeds United</span> tied`

So now you may want this string as an array of html content

```js
let contentsArray = parentString.split("\r\n")
```

Now we have this:

```
 [
  "",
  "<span>Manchester United</span> won",
  "<span>Manchester City</span> lost",
  "<span>Leeds United</span> tied"
 ]
```

Finally if you want to get rid of that initial empty string just shift the array once

```js
contentsArray.shift()
```

Comment: duplicated item.value can't be handled can you give my similar solution using start and end indexes @twosaturdayscode

Comment: @imPK I've edited my answer according to your observations, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you can try this code :

```
let parentString = '\r\nManchester United won\r\nManchester City lost\r\nLeeds United tied'

let replaceValues = [
    {value: 'Manchester United', startIndex: 2, endIndex: 19},
    {value: 'Manchester City', startIndex: 25, endIndex: 40},
    {value: 'Leeds United', startIndex: 47, endIndex: 59},
];

replaceValues.sort((a,b) => b.startIndex - a.startIndex);

function replaceAt(input, start, end, value) {
    let str = input.split('')
    str.splice(start, end - start, value);
    return str.join('');
}

for(let replace of replaceValues) {
    parentString = replaceAt(parentString,replace.startIndex, replace.endIndex, `<span class='replace-text-{{i}}'>${replace.value}</span>`);
}

console.log(parentString);

// Output :
// <span class='replace-text-{{i}}'>Manchester United</span> won
// <span class='replace-text-{{i}}'>Manchester City</span> lost
// <span class='replace-text-{{i}}'>Leeds United</span> tied
```

I don't know where does `{{i}}` comes from, but I think you can easily fill it will the correct value

Answer (score -1):

Maybe regex is slightly faster? Seems like you indend to get rid of line breaks?

```js
const parentString = '\r\nManchester United won\r\nManchester City lost\r\nLeeds United tied'
const repalcedString = parentString.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
console.log(repalcedString)
```